# SQL how to select product where each data has a duration less than 300000 ms

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the following query I am trying to grab upcs where all isrcs have a duration less than  300000 ms where the number of tracks is 11 and where the owning territory is not in 31,201,41,125) with this query

```
select  r.UPC ,r.Id, res.ISRC , res.Duration ,COUNT( res.ISRC) from Release r 
inner join ReleaseResource rr on rr.ReleaseId=r.Id
inner join Resource res on res.Id=rr.ResourceId
inner join ReleaseTerritory rt on rt.ReleaseId=r.id
where   not r.OwningTerritoryId in (31,201,41,125) and res.Duration<5*60000 and  r.TrackCount=11 and rt.IsDeleted=0
group by r.UPC ,r.Id, res.ISRC , res.Duration
having COUNT( distinct rt.TerritoryId)=10  
order by r.upc
```

the result i get is good except for the isrc where the query shows only the isrcs that has less than 300000 ms but when i look inside the upc i find that there are other isrcs that have a duration more then 300000 ms.
Do you what I should modify in order to have only the upcs with all isrcs less than  300000 ms. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are filtering out the 'duration less than 300000 ms' before the GROUPING ..
Remove the filter from WHERE and try this in HAVING

```
select  r.UPC ,r.Id, res.ISRC , res.Duration ,COUNT( res.ISRC) from Release r 
inner join ReleaseResource rr on rr.ReleaseId=r.Id
inner join Resource res on res.Id=rr.ResourceId
inner join ReleaseTerritory rt on rt.ReleaseId=r.id
where   not r.OwningTerritoryId in (31,201,41,125) and  r.TrackCount=11 and rt.IsDeleted=0
group by r.UPC ,r.Id, res.ISRC , res.Duration
having COUNT( distinct rt.TerritoryId)=10  AND MAX(res.Duration)<5*60000
order by r.upc
```

Comment: it still takes isrcs with duration more than 5*60000

Comment: It worked when i Removed res.isrc and res.duration from the select :)